# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'xxx.xxx.XX' (60) (MariaDB 10.8)

Tags: mariadb, homebrew

Since a day or so I can not access the databases on two of my servers any longer

I use

`mysql -h host.sld.TLD -P 3306 -user user`

which I have configured to allow my user from my host without password

but get the above error.

However, when I use

`telnet host.sld.TLD 3306`

I get

`5.5.5-10.8.5-MariaDB-1:10.8.5+maria~ubu2004(si4cyW'Y��-n;{ypDA\)VU)mysql_native_passwordC`

I am using homebrew's mariadb (currently 10.9.3) on my machine, which I can reach from the outside. One each of the 'failed' remotes is on ubuntu with 10.8 and one on a Mac also with 10.8, and outgoing works from both. OpenSSL is version 1.1.1s on both Macs

I have installed a number of different mariadb versions all have the same issues, as do their perl libraries. mysql itself works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONC-612) has been fixed in MariaDB 10.9.4 which was released yesterday. Brew still offers 10.9.3, usually it takes a couple of days until latest 10.9 release will be available via brew.

The issue doesn't affect the server itself, but Connector/C and command line tools which link against Connector/C.

See also: [MariaDB connector in Python cannot connect to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73550534/mariadb-connector-in-python-cannot-connect-to-remote-server)